# Storage downloading costs too much for Firestore app in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So the way my app is working is kind of like instagram. A user can upload a photo, and whenever someone loads the app it downloads each picture that was uploaded from the firebase.

I understand that I need to buy space or change my plan, but I didn't do that much and I'm wasting 1.7gb from a user in like an hour. Each photo costs like 17mb to upload and download.

I am not sure what I can do to lessen my downloading here.

The way I download from firestore is like this from the f:

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
islandRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 10240 * 10240) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
// Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
// Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

And each time it loads a photo into a collectionviewcontroller. Which means it is like 17mb for each photo which is a lot. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is where you want to make a decision about the level of quality for the photos that you upload to firebase. I can assure you that instagram and any other social media platform only store versions of your pictures that are compressed and optimized for size.

You can easily compress your image by doing something like this

```
let data = imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)
```

you would then upload that new compressed version of the image to firebase and dramatically improve your storage efficiency.

Comment: Is this the only possible way to improve my memory by downloading stuff from firestore? There isn't a way around it really? Thanks

Comment: When dealing with storage costs your options are to either store fewer things, make the things smaller, or just pay more money

Comment: So if instagram were to use firestore, they'd pay a fortune then right? (I doubt they do anyways lol)

Comment: Well instagram isn’t the best example because they are storing billions of pictures so yes they pay a lot of money in storage fees. The point is that they need to be efficient about it. The result of Instagram compressing user pictures to 50% of its original quality or 30% is likely orders of magnitude in savings